# Chromium - libffmpeg problem

Tags: chromium

When starting chromium-browser from terminal I get:

```
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser: error while loading shared libraries: libffmpeg.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried reinstalling ffmpeg which didn't work. How can I fix this ?

Comment: If the answer below solves your problem, don't forget to accept it clicking on the tick on the left side.

Answer (score 1):

From [comment by OP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/704003/chromium-will-not-start-libffmpeg-problem#comment1033625_704010)

The issue is solved by the command:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg
```